# How to exclude some maven project from sonar analysis

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I have many(Let say 10 (A, B, C...)) eclipse plugin which is maven based.

I have one master pom file which includes all other plugin projects. 
now by building master file with `sonar:sonar` goal it will build all the plugins.

**So my question:** Is there is any way so that I can exclude some plugin let say A and C.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **NOTE:** This property is deprecated since version 4.3 and should not be used anymore.

From the [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-Exclusions/Inclusions), there is an option to skip module using `sonar.skippedModules`

You could also do this from the sonar admin page as documented in the Skipping Modules section [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus).

Comment: Note that :" This property is deprecated since version 4.3 and should not be used anymore."

Answer (score 62):

There are several ways, one of which is adding the `sonar.skip` property inside the `pom.xml` of the project / module you want to skip.

This excludes a project from SonarQube analysis:

```
<properties>
    <sonar.skip>true</sonar.skip>
</properties>
```

This also works with Jenkins and running Sonar as a post build action.

For more details see: [Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for Maven](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-ExcludingamodulefromSonarQubeanalysis)

Answer (score 1):

I had no luck with the officially documented `sonar.skip`: when I set it in a submodule POM, I saw

```
[INFO] Delaying SonarQube Scanner to the end of multi-module project
```

after modules which should have been included and then

```
[INFO] sonar.skip = true: Skipping analysis
```

at the end of the reactor build, and there was no analysis/upload.

Instead I defined `sonar.exclusions` in the root POM to a [pattern](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.4/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/) matching the source files (by package path) which would be used in the submodule to be skipped. This seems to have worked.

---

As an aside, setting `sonar.projectKey` in the root POM did not work; Sonar complained that

```
Project '…' can't have 2 modules with the following key: …
```

which I fixed by moving this to `.mvn/maven.config`:

```
-Dsonar.projectKey=…
```